# Prove that an action is well-defined.

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group and $H \leq G$. Let $X$ be the set of right cosets of $H$ in $G$, and define an action of $G$ on $X$ by $$\pi_g(Hf)=H(fg^{-1}).$$ Show that $\pi_g$ is well-defined for every $g$ and that $\pi$ really is an action.

---

Now, by the definition of "well-defined" we must show that $\pi_g(Hf)=\pi_g(Hk)$ whenever $Hf=Hk$. OK, so $Hf=Hk$ implies that $f^{-1}k \in H$ by the coset lemma, but where do we go from here?

Comment: You have rewritten the hypothesis $Hf=Hk$. Have you rewritten the conclusion $\pi_g(Hf)=\pi_g(Hk)$?

Comment: $Hf = Hk \Rightarrow kf^{-1} \in H$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$Hf = Hk \Rightarrow kf^{-1} \in H$

$\pi_g(Hf) = Hfg^{-1} = Hkf^{-1}fg^{-1} = Hkg^{-1} = \pi_g(Hk)$

It is obvious that $\pi_e(Hf) = Hf$

Furthermore $\pi_g(\pi_h(Hf)) = \pi_g(Hfh^{-1}) = Hfh^{-1}g^{-1} = Hf(gh)^{-1} = \pi_{gh}(Hf)$

Answer (score 2):

The lemma you state works both ways: if $kf^{-1}\in H$, then $Hf=Hk$.  From here, one can check:

$kg^{-1}(fg^{-1})^{-1}=kg^{-1}gf^{-1}=kf^{-1}\in H$

Thus, we see that $Hkg^{-1}=Hfg^{-1}$.  From here it remains to see that $\pi_g$ is really an action.

Answer (score 1):

The coset $Hf$ consists of elements of the form $hf$ for each $h \in H$, i.e. $Hf = \{ hf \: | \: h \in H \}$. Suppose $Hf= Hk$. Then $\{hf \: | \: h \in H \} = \{ hk \: | \: h \in H \}$, so for each $h \in H$ there exists some $h^\prime\in H$ such that $hf= h^\prime k$. Each element of $\pi_g (Hf)$ is of the form $hfg^{-1}$ for some $h\in H$, and $hfg^{-1}= h^\prime k g^{-1}$, so $\pi_g (Hf)\subseteq \pi_g(Hk).$ Showing the other inclusion is analogous.